# How to find files with trailing slash in linux

Tags: linux, files, find

I have some files in the filesystem that end with a trailing slash like so:

```
my_text_file_1.txt\
some_other_file_2.pl\
```

I usually use *find* for these cases, but the following did not work:

```
find . -name "*\\"
```

Anybody have any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can double-escape it or use single quotes:

```
find . -name "*\\\\" -print
find . -name '*\\' -print
```

Comment: Nice. Exactly what i need. While I wait 9 mins to accept your answer... can you explain why i need to double escape?

Comment: @superspace: It's the difference between single and double quotes in `bash` (and I think any other shell). In double quoted strings, it will still expand meta characters, so it would have first turned `\\` into `\` as you expect. However that is then passed to `find` as `"*\"`, where `find` expands it again. `\"` is a literal `"` character, leaving `find` looking for files matching `"*"`. Double-escaping gets around that the fun way; and using single quotes tells the shell to pass everything on to the command unchanged.